# SSD requires HDD to boot Windows

Tags: windows, boot

I've got an unusual situation. After cleaning my PC it turned out that in order to boot into Windows my machine requires both the HDD and SSD in order to boot.

Running only on SSD causes a black screen with cursor.
Running only on HDD causes a Windows information that there are devices missing in order to boot.

It's like to boot instructions are on the HDD but Windows is on SSD. I'm not sure what caused it.

Is there a way to "fix" it without formatting any of the drives?

EDIT 1:

> bcdedit /v

Shows something interesting. The `Boot Manager` is on D: (HDD), and the `Boot Loader` is on C: (SSD)

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  pl-PL
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {c9ee9348-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
resumeobject            {c9ee9347-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
displayorder            {c9ee9348-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c9ee9348-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  pl-PL
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {c9ee9349-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {c9ee9347-24c6-11ea-98a6-cb2913871533}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

EDIT 2: [It seems](https://superuser.com/q/1419840/660188) that I'm not the only one with this issue and it might be casued by a windows update.

Comment: What is on the SSD? It appears that Windows is installed on the HDD... The quick fix then would be remove the SSD (temporarily) and boot Windows install media and repair boot making everything be on the HDD, but what is the end result you want here?

Comment: Windows is on SSD, (C:/Windows). HDD (D:) is almost empty